# Magento Error - Failed to load node from config

Tags: database, magento-enterprise

I have a Magento 1 Enterprise site where this error has recently occurred.

`Failed to load node  from config`

(notice there is a small gap in between the words 'node' and 'from')

This error is being produced when adding an item to the cart, then proceeding to onepage checkout from the cart.

I'm not 100% positive, but I believe the error began occurring after an unintentional install of the SFC_CimCore and SFC_CimSaved modules (those were later removed). There is a standing upgrade of the SFC_AuthnetToken module (v1.1.0).

This appears to look like a corrupted EAV, but I'm not seeing any upgrade scripts in those modules that would've produced this error.

Any thoughts?

The full stack is here:

```
Failed to load node  from config

#0 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Config.php(61): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Failed to load ...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Abstract.php(82): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Config->getAllOptions()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Select.php(122): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract->getOptionText('0')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Select.php(139): Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data_Select->_getOptionText('0')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/local/Block/CustomerMaster/Block/Customer/Address/Renderer/Default.php(57): Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data_Select->outputValue('html')
#5 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php(326): Block_CustomerMaster_Block_Customer_Address_Renderer_Default->render(Object(Block_CustomerMaster_Model_Customer_Address))
#6 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/local/Alpine/Myblock/Block/Checkout/Onepage/Billing.php(34): Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract->format('html')
#7 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/design/frontend/blockco/block/template/myblock/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml(20): Alpine_Myblock_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Billing->getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing')
#8 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#9 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/blockc...')
#10 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(867): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(586): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(530): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('billing', true)
#14 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/design/frontend/blockco/default/template/checkout/onepage.phtml(47): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('billing')
#15 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#16 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/blockc...')
#17 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(867): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(867): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#21 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(586): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(530): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#23 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/design/frontend/blockco/block/template/page/1column.phtml(48): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#24 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#25 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/blockc...')
#26 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#27 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(867): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#30 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(210): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#31 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->indexAction()
#32 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#33 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#34 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#35 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#36 /var/www/vhosts/blockandcompany.com/html/index.php(97): Mage::run('', 'store')
#37 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out not to be with the 2 SFC modules mentioned, but with a custom module that installed a customer attribute. The module was later removed but the attribute was left behind and it had nothing to populate it, which caused a fatal error.

Drilling down to the following file helped determine the attribute index and name:

`app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Select.php`

The function at lines 112-115 returned `0`, which was the index of the attribute.

On line 124 in `public function outputValue`, the following included the name of the attribute.

```
$value = $this->getEntity()->getData($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
```

Once I realized which attribute it was, I could access it through the admin panel under `Customers > Attribute > Manage Customer Attributes`.

I changed "Show on Frontend" from Yes to No and it fixed the fatal error.